# Goto random page on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple mobile website where I want to display random content on a button click.  I am using a simple piece of javascript/jquery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var randomlinks=[];
randomlinks[0]="_1"
randomlinks[1]="_2"
randomlinks[2]="_3"
randomlinks[3]="_4"
randomlinks[4]="_5"
randomlinks[5]="_6"
randomlinks[6]="_7"
randomlinks[7]="_8"
randomlinks[8]="_9"
randomlinks[9]="_10"

function randomlink(){
 var idx = Math.floor(Math.random()*randomlinks.length);

 $.mobile.changePage('#' + randomlinks[idx], {transition:'pop'});
}
</script>
```

And I am calling the function using:

```
<a href="javascript:randomlink()" id="nextComp" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Next Comp</a>
```

I know there are better ways of calling the function but that is another issue.

The script is after jquery mobile links.

In the javascript console from chrome I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'changePage' of undefined forhim.php:681
randomlink forhim.php:681
(anonymous function)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you including the jQuery Mobile library in the page? Because that error is saying `$.mobile` is undefined. Since it is not saying `$` is undefined, you must be including the jQuery library, but you also need to include the jQuery Mobile library.

Comment: This is a very good way of irritating your visitors to your web site

Comment: @EdHeal That depends entirely on what the purpose of this site is.

Comment: There is a perfectly good reason for the randomness, but that is by the by.

Comment: @brad - I guess a site where you cannot bookmark a page. As to a 'perfect' reason I am struggling with that in this context

Comment: Honestly, it needs to be random, but it's really nothing to do with the question asked.

Comment: @EdHeal Perhaps one of those "show me random content" sites

Answer (score 0):

Try binding to the function during the jQM pageinit event on the main page instead of via the href:

```
<a href="#" id="nextComp" data-inline="true" data-theme="a" data-role="button" data-corners="false" data-icon="arrow-r" data-iconpos="right">Next Comp</a>

$(document).on("pageinit", "#page1", function(){   
    $(document).on("click", "#nextComp", function(){
        randomlink();
    });
});
```

> Here is a working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/VLQnj/)**